# TCP client socket filling up heap

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, serversocket

Using java socket library and what I see is that when the server accepts the tcp connection but not read data from the buffer and in the meantime our client keep pumping heavy data, client side heap size grows to max available and crushes the  client application.
Is there anyway I can limit the socket buffer size or whatever using that heap and if it is violated, connection is killed? This way client can detect client detect the connection is gone and

Client Side;

```
  this.socket = new Socket(server, port);
  this.socket.setKeepAlive(true);
  this.outwriter = new OutputStreamWriter(this.socket.getOutputStream());
  this.outwriter.write(o.toString());
```

Server Side;

```
conn = serverSocket.accept();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not cause by the socket. You have a memory leak elsewhere in your application. The behaviour you describe will eventually block in the `write()` method and will not consume any heap memory whatsoever.

Comment: write() is not a blocking call. I have a queue and read from the queue then write it to the socket.write(). According to graphite queue size not growing, this tells me that thread successfully calls the write and remove that item from the queue after that When the server reads from the buffer as client pumps data, heap size is stable.

Comment: You are mistaken. `OutputStream.write()` *is* a blocking call, as is `Writer.write()`. Socket writes go into the socket send buffer, which is (a) a fixed size and (b) in the kernel, not the Java heap. Your theory doesnt make sense. Try another one.

Comment: Clearly the queue is filling up, due to the write blocking, due to the send buffer filling up, due to the peer not reading. I would get rid of the queue altogether and use a synchronized send method.

Comment: the queue is used to batch records and then it puhes to google big query in batches. Within the same thread, it is now pushing records to subscribers. After each batch, it reports to queue size to graphite, so we know exactly the size of the queue. If write() blocks, then the thread should be stalled but this is not the case, data continue to follow to nosql. I believe we are missing something. I can also see this behavior in UT. I can pump millions records size of a GB and write() still fine though server not processing the data and memory is exploting

Comment: Yes, you are right. write() is blocking call. I should spin off another threat to oush the batch to serversocket.

Answer (score 0):

You can use socket.setSendBufferSize().

Though this would help in testing your theory,as mentioned by @EJP, the heap leak will not be due to send buffer getting filled up. In which case the write operation will return error.

Comment: He can indeed but it won't fix this problem.

Comment: @EJP. Yes. I agree. I will leave the answer though.  Let the OP use it and test his theory

Comment: The write operation will block, not return an error. I don't see how using an irrelevant setting will test anything.

Comment: this would not help as it is to throttle the speed as far as i know. Client gets alot of data and pushes the data to the server if connection is open. So I should either close the connection or be able to check the current buffer size in the client then skip socket.write

Comment: @East2West The only way you can do that is via NIO. But the socket isn't your problem in the first place. You're barking up the wrong tree.